# how multiply a ranges of values for other value on python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator

I need multiply ranges>1.5 and <=4.5 * 9,
but I am new in this type of language.
please help me.

```
def CalcD(Level_water)
  if Level>1.5 and <=4,5 * 9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using ArcGIS field calculator

```
def CalcD(level):
  if 1.5 <= level <= 4.5 :
    return level * 9
  else:
    return level
```

CalcD(!Level_water!)

Comment: @radouxkju please consult the zen of python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/